# A riddle: Which is not working--sites.php or my vhost setup?

Tags: apache, drupal-7

I am beside myself. I own these 3 Drupal 7 sites on-line that I manage with GIT. I don't use the default site, just the 3 multi-sites. I just want to access the local versions in my browser, but I cannot. I copied the following from the local code base.

I have spent about three or four days over the last year trying to find the source of my grief but to no avail. I would really appreciate an expert diagnosis.

Default site, not used.

### Sub sites:

```
main/sites/abc.com
main/sites/def.org
main/sites/xyz.com
```

### sites.php:

```
$sites['localhost.main'] = 'default';
$sites['localhost.abc'] = 'abc.com';
$sites['localhost.def'] = 'def.org';
$sites['localhost.xyz'] = 'xyz.com';
```

### I think this works

(When removed, Sites folder does not load) --> /Users/Peanut/Sites/vhosts/localhost.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Users/Peanut/Sites
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

### I think this works

(I get the install form)  --> /Users/Peanut/Sites/vhosts/main.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Users/Peanut/Sites/main
    ServerName main
</VirtualHost>
```

### So I assume this also works

--> /Users/Peanut/Sites/vhosts/abc.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Users/Peanut/Sites/main
    ServerName abc
</VirtualHost>
```

### This site mysteriously still loads when I delete this file

, which is a separate single-site install of drupal 7  --> /Users/Peanut/Sites/vhosts/othersite.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Users/Peanut/Sites/othersite
    ServerName othersite
</VirtualHost>
```

### .htaccess in drupal root contains:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^def.org$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.def\.org\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^xyz\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.xyz\.com\/" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.abc\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.abc\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "https\:\/\/www\.abc\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

### /etc/hosts:

```
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       main
127.0.0.1       abc
127.0.0.1       def
127.0.0.1       xyz
127.0.0.1       othersite

55.255.255.255  broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

### /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf:

```
# Virtual hosts
  Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

# Virtual host files that Peanut created, one for each site.
  Include /Users/Peanut/Sites/vhosts/*.conf
```

### /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extras/httpd-vhosts.conf

contains the following, both of which I have tried:

```
 NameVirtualHost *:80
#NameVirtualHost *
```

Answer (score 0):

I might try scrapping your MAMP install, and trying following a guided install such as this one - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sEe12h9Lryo

Not a great answer, I know, but perhaps it'll help.

Comment: Hi Kellen. Thanks for taking the time. The video you linked to was of no help. Any better ideas? Maybe you can spot an error in the code I pasted?

Comment: @dillon I'm not great with VM configuration. I normally have a backend developer do that work, but I'll take a look at my setup and see if anything sticks out. You may have more luck if you posted on the Drupal stack exchange - http://drupal.stackexchange.com/ The Drupal forums may also be a good place. Are you certain MAMP uses the localhost IP for websites? I know vagrant uses a user-set IP, separate from the localhost IP.

Comment: Hi Kellen. That is over my head. Other sites I have locally work, but they are single-site installs of drupal. It is just the secondary sites on this one multi-site install that is the problem. I posted a link here at https://www.drupal.org/node/2847885 .

Comment: Oh sorry, I misread. Not sure if you've see this already, but the second answer goes into a lot of detail of setting up a multi-site. - https://www.drupal.org/node/1043102

Answer (score 0):

## Solved.

Now I can reach the local sites with this url pattern...

```
    http://dev.abc
```

### sites.php:

```
$sites['dev.defaultsite'] = 'default';
$sites['dev.abc'] = 'abc.com';
$sites['dev.def'] = 'def.org';
$sites['dev.xyz'] = 'xyz.com';
```

### This works

--> /Users/Peanut/Sites/vhosts/defaultsite.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Users/Peanut/Sites/main
    ServerName dev.defaultsite
</VirtualHost>
```

--> /Users/Peanut/Sites/vhosts/abc.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Users/Peanut/Sites/main
    ServerName dev.abc
</VirtualHost>
```

--> /Users/Peanut/Sites/vhosts/def.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Users/Peanut/Sites/main
    ServerName dev.def
</VirtualHost>
```

### /etc/hosts:

```
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       dev.defaultsite
127.0.0.1       dev.abc
127.0.0.1       dev.def
127.0.0.1       dev.xyz
127.0.0.1       dev.othersite

55.255.255.255  broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
```

### /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/httpd.conf:

```
# Virtual hosts
  Include /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

# Virtual host files that Peanut created, one for each site.
  Include /Users/Peanut/Sites/vhosts/*.conf
```

### /Applications/MAMP/conf/apache/extras/httpd-vhosts.conf

contains the following:

```
 NameVirtualHost *:80
#NameVirtualHost *
```

I don't know if it helped, but I did change the base_url in settings.php to:

```
    $base_url = 'http://dev.abc';  // NO trailing slash!
```